# MQOPEN gives error 2085, which I didn't have before

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I have everything was working OK, until today I on MQOPEN got error
    2085 MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <cmqc.h>    
#include <cmqxc.h>     
#include "dte_mq.h"    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

typedef struct tagDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR    
{    
    MQHOBJ handle;    
    int    IsSyncpointControled;    
} DTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR, *PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR;    

static MQHCONN sHConn = 0;    
static MQLONG  sCompCode = MQCC_OK;    
static MQLONG  sReason = MQRC_NONE;    
static int     sNumOpenQueues = 0;    
static PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR sQueues = NULL;    
MQLONG   OpenCode;    
MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor */    
MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    
MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};    
MQLONG   O_options;/* MQCONNX options */    
MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};    
/* Client connection channel */    
MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};    



#define MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES     10    



int dteMqOpen(const char *name, int *qd)    
{    
    MQLONG   options;     
    MQHOBJ   hObj;    
    int      i;    
    printf("SAM\n");    
    strncpy(od.ObjectName, name, MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
    printf("SAM2\n");    
    O_options = MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;    
    printf("SAM3\n");    
    MQOPEN(sHConn, &od, O_options, &hObj, &sCompCode, &sReason);    
    printf("MQopen = %d and %d\n",sCompCode,sReason);    
    if (sCompCode != MQCC_OK)    
    {    
        printf("RETURN %d\n",DTE_MQR_FAILED);    
        return DTE_MQR_FAILED;    
   }    
   ++sNumOpenQueues;    
  *qd = 1;    
  for(i = 0; i < MAX_NUM_OPEN_QUEUES; i++)    
  {    
      printf("In the loop1\n");    
      if(sQueues[i].handle == -1)    
      {    
          *qd = i;    
          printf("QDESC1 = %d\n",qd);    
          sQueues[i].handle = hObj;    
          sQueues[i].IsSyncpointControled = 0;    
          break;    
     }    
     printf("In the loop\n");    
   }    
   printf("QDESC = %d\n",qd);    
   return DTE_MQR_OK;    
}
```

Function call is:

```
qd = -1;    
dteretopen = dteMqOpen(QName, &qd);    
printf ("Return code from dteMqOpen = %d\n",dteretopen);    
if (dteretopen ==0)    
{    
    printf("MQOPEN could not open MQ, check errpr log\n");    
    exit(99);    
}
```

> Error 2085. But several days before there was no such error
>   Connection is OK, but MQOPEN failed

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` pointers.

Comment: But it have been working for the last 15  years

Comment: So you wrote bad code the last 15 years. How did you ensure qualifier-correctness? And instead of `*` you type `P`. Nothing saved, but a lot of problems.

Comment: I can do it, but what is the reason?

Comment: I gave you _one_ reason. Others are it is just confusing, one should write **readable and maintainable** code..

Comment: Interesting. What did I give you? I have been changing old program to connect to different MQ from Linux. What else do you need?

Comment: I put P instead *, and it gave me a million errors. Where did you see such pointer notation? And I didn't read the code, I am changing it now

Comment: Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Please provide the queue name parameter that you are using in this program, and show us the queue definition on the queue manager you connected to when it failed. Are you sure the queue exists on the queue manager? Remember that case is important.

Answer (score 2):

```
dteretopen = dteMqOpen(QName, &qd);
```

Clearly 'QName' has an invalid value.

You have been posting question after question about the same program.  Obviously, you have zero training in MQ programming.  You need to get some MQ training ASAP. There is lots and lots of information on the web and videos too.

Why aren't you doing some basic debugging and outputting 'QName?

You need to take some initiative in debugging your program before posting questions here.  We are not here to do your work.

Comment: Obviously, you are talking and don't know about what. QName is valid. I have re-run the program again and have to go back to my previous question, because MQOPEN is working, but MQPUT gives segmentation fault

Comment: BS.  I have 20+ years working with MQ, I know EXACTLY what I'm talking about. RC of 2085 means you supplied an INVALID queue name.  Instead of mouthing off, why don't you look up RC 2085 in the MQ Knowledge Center.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041480_.htm  Better yet, why don't you go to MQ Technical Conference ( http://www.mqtechconference.com ) and get some training in MQ.  Morag Hughson is doing several MQ programming sessions.

Comment: you were correct, this was our MQ staff problem. Thanks